# Why @SafeVarargs is RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME in contrast to @SuppressWarnings is SOURCE?

Tags: java, annotations

Roles of `@SuppressWarnings` and `@SafeVarargs` **suppress warnings**. Both of them are *similar* because of that.

I think `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` is enough for `@SafeVarargs` like `@SuppressWarnings`. Does it have a reason?

In `java.lang`

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SuppressWarnings {

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SafeVarargs {
```